# How could I update my data dynamically from MySQL with logstash (without duplicate)?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I have configured logstash.conf to insert dynamically the data of my database but the issue is :

when I change a line of my table that line is not updated in my index because I only insert new values after sql_last_value, I though about us a trigger but I don't sure how can I do it.

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string =>"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog"
    jdbc_user =>"root"
    jdbc_password =>""
    jdbc_driver_library =>"C:\Users\saidb\Downloads\mysql-connector-java-5.1.47\mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class =>"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    schedule =>"* * * * *"
    statement =>"SELECT * FROM blog_pro WHERE id >:sql_last_value"
    use_column_value =>true
    tracking_column =>id
    }
  }
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts =>"localhost:9200"
    index =>"blog_pro"
    document_type =>"data"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have a column with a last_modified date, you can track that column instead of the ID one.

Comment: use mutate => update to update instead of insert (based on a key)

Comment: @LeBigCat could you more specify ?

Comment: @Val no I don't have date column

Comment: look at mutate on logstash. You can add a bloc in order to update document according to a pattern (id) instead of insert it.

Comment: `change a line` means you perform an `update` action right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `id` to select rows you cannot do that.
You have 2 options,

1. select all the rows each time and send them into ES using query `SELECT * FROM blog_pro`, which I dont think is a good one to do based on you scenario.
2. create a new column `last_modified_time` which contain the last modified timestamp of the record(row). then use that to filter rows. note the property `tracking_column_type => "timestamp"`

`statement =>"SELECT * FROM blog_pro WHERE last_modiefied_time >:sql_last_value"
    use_column_value =>true
    tracking_column =>last_modified_time
    tracking_column_type => "timestamp"`

here is full logstash config

```
input { 

 jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string =>"jdbc:mysql://192.168.3.57:3306/blog_pro"
    jdbc_user =>"dush"
    jdbc_password =>"dush"
    jdbc_driver_library =>"F:\logstash-6.2.2\bin\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class =>"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    schedule =>"* * * * *"
    statement =>"SELECT * FROM blog_pro WHERE last_modified_time  >:sql_last_value"
    use_column_value =>true
    tracking_column =>last_modified_time
    tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
    } 
 }

output 
{ 
    #output to elasticsearch    
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "192.168.1.245:9201" ]
        action=>update
        # "%{id}" - > primary key of the table 
        document_id => "%{id}"
        doc_as_upsert =>true
    }

}
```

note you may need to clear your index and start indexing with this configuration. I tested this and works fine.

Elasticsearch version = 5.x.x

logstash version =6.2.2

Comment: I'm testing your solution and I note that when I change a line of my table, the program don't changes my line but it insert another line with my modification in my index

Comment: can you mention your logstash `output{}`  if you want to update a document in elasticsearch you have to set parameter `action=>update` in the elasticsearch output pulgin settings

Comment: thank you , I understood that I must use mutate update but How can I do it ? can you explain me with an example like table with title and date for example.

Comment: Thank you !!!! that's work, but must not clear the index or logstash will index just the doc which was modified.